# Sorting numpy array according to the sum

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sort an numpy array according to the sum.
Something like

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,8], [3,0,2,1])
b = np.sum(a, axis = 0)
idx = b.argsort()
```

Now np.take(a, idx) leads to [2, 1, 3, 8].

But I would like an array: result = np.array([2, 1, 3, 8], [0, 3, 2, 1]]

What is the most clever and fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the same code from your question, you can just use the optional `axis` argument for `np.take` (default the flattened array is used, that's the reason you got only the first row, see [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)):

```
>>> np.take(a, idx, axis=1)
array([[2, 1, 3, 8],
       [0, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Or you can use fancy indexing:

```
>>> a[:,idx]
array([[2, 1, 3, 8],
       [0, 3, 2, 1]])
```